# Multindex Join, Column Names

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame `df1` with columns `logfile, pos, category, value`.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'logfile': ['log1.log', 'log1.log', 'log1.log', 'log2.log'],
                    'pos': [1, 2, 3, 1],
                    'category': ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat2'],
                    'value' : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]})
```

I compute on `df1` a count operation for each logfile, position and category:

```
res1 = df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).agg(['count'])
```

I would like to join the resulting DataFrame `res` to another DataFrame `df2` which has columns `logfile, pos, calc`.

Example:

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'logfile': ['log1.log','log2.log'],
                'pos': [1, 2],
                'calc': [0.7, 0.9]})
```

Following what I found in similar questions, I do:

```
res1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['logfile', 'pos'])
```

However, now I get as a result a DataFrame with columns `logfile, pos, (logfile,), (pos,), (category,), (value,count), calc`. I somehow cannot access the columns by reasonable names.

If I, instead, remove `reset_index` before merging, the `category` column is gone.

What I would like to have is a DataFrame with normal column names, but without loosing the column `category`.

I have Pandas in version 0.25 using in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: could you add  a data sample ?

Comment: Sorry for that! I added an example

Comment: The problem is that `res1` has multi-indexed columns while `df2` does not, what do you want it to look like after mege?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `as_index=False` in the `groupby` operation.

```
res1 = df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category'], as_index=False).agg('count')
res1.merge(df2, on=['logfile', 'pos'], suffixes=('_old', '_new'))
```

**Update**
With your provided examples:

```
df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category'], as_index=False).agg('count').merge(df2, on=['logfile', 'pos'])
```

returns

```
    logfile    pos  category    value   calc
0   log1.log    1   cat1           1    0.7
```

Comment: But with your solution, I don't have the `category` column in the results. And the suffixes are somehow ignored, as well.

Comment: I updated my answer with the results that you provided. If can't seem to find any variable in your environment that would prevent you from reproducing the results, specially that this is a very straight forward operation.

Answer (score 2):

When you did your first `groupby`, you didn't focus on the `value` column and you aggregated with a list.  This left you with a `MultiIndex` column object.

```
res1

                      value
                      count
logfile  pos category      
log1.log 1   cat1         1
         2   cat2         1
         3   cat1         1
log2.log 1   cat2         1
```

You could have

```
df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).agg('count')
# df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).count()

                       value
logfile  pos category       
log1.log 1   cat1          1
         2   cat2          1
         3   cat1          1
log2.log 1   cat2          1
```

OR

```
df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).value.agg(['count'])

                       count
logfile  pos category       
log1.log 1   cat1          1
         2   cat2          1
         3   cat1          1
log2.log 1   cat2          1
```

This would leave you with a "Single" Index object

```
res1 = df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).value.agg(['count'])
res1.merge(df2, on=['logfile', 'pos'])

    logfile  pos  count  calc
0  log1.log    1      1   0.7
```

OR

```
res1 = df1.groupby(['logfile', 'pos', 'category']).count()
res1.merge(df2, on=['logfile', 'pos'])

    logfile  pos  value  calc
0  log1.log    1      1   0.7
```

Comment: Great explanation!  +1

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Why is the column `category` gone after the merge?